# Get current time in select in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
$product = Product::select('id', 'name', 'status',DB::raw('date(\'d-m-y\') as dateCurrent' ))
    ->whereDate('status', 3)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Result `dateCurrent` **null** :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => 'Iphone'
            [dateCurrent] => null
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => 'samsung'
            [dateCurrent] => null
        )
)
```

I want to get current time right at select. Is there any way to get it? Thanks

Comment: Is there any issue you are facing in this code?

Comment: Why do you have the dates in `(d-m-y)` and not in `('Y-m-d')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date('d-m-y')
```

looks like php built function
if u want to db time
u can use NOW() function
and if u use db time

```
$product = Product::select('id', 'name', 'status', DB::raw('NOW() AS dateCurrent'))
                            ->whereDate('status', 3)
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();
```

but u want php server time

```
$product = Product::select(
'id', 'name',
'status', DB::raw(sprintf('%s AS dateCurrent', date('d-m-y'))))
                            ->whereDate('status', 3)
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now